# Java Server Socket binding multiple domain/host names

Tags: java, serversocket

I have a java nio server with ip address 192.168.0.1 listening on port 80. I configured this server to bind to multiple domain/host names, let's say server1, server2, server3 are all resolved as 192.168.0.1.

Now I'm hoping if the client connects to server1, on the server side, I can recognize that the client is connecting to server1 instead of other names or direct ip address, so that I can do something special, and if the client is connecting to server2, I can recognize that the client is requesting server2, so I can do something else special, and so on.

Now the question is: seems on the server side, I cannot easily get the correct information which server name my clients are connecting to.

I have the follow code:

```
ServerSocketChannel ssChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) selKey.channel();
String boundHost = sChannel.socket().getLocalAddress().getHostName();
```

But it does not work, the boundHost is always the server1 even if clients connect to server2 or server3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot obtain this kind of information from sockets: sockets don't know about host names, only IP addresses.

If you take the example of HTTP, what distinguishes a host from the other one is the `Host` header in the HTTP header.

You can therefore only distinguish different servers if the protocol you use has the hostname information in it.

Comment: Thanks fge for answering. So is there any possibility that Java, or even C can obtain this information? Actually I'm hoping to make a TCP layer multiplexer/proxy. I know Apache2 has a proxy module which actually hacks into the protocol to obtain this information. But I don't want to do that. I'm hoping to make it completely transparent from the up layer protocols.

Comment: Or it's just technically absolutely not possible? Thanks.